# I get an error when I try to compile DAR on 12.04, how can I fix solve this?

Tags: software-installation, make, archive, configure

Install DAR 2.4.12 from source because latest version ubuntu package is 2.4.2.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

dar and libdar have been successfully configured with the following parameters:

```
  LIBDAR parameters:
   Zlib compression (gzip)    : YES
   Libbz2 compression (bzip2) : YES
   Liblzo2 compression (lzo)  : NO
   Strong encryption support  : YES
   Extended Attributes support: NO
   Large files support (> 2GB): YES
   ext2fs NODUMP flag support : NO
   Special allocation scheme  : YES
   Integer size used          : infinint
   Thread safe support        : YES
   Furtive read mode          : YES
   Large directory optim.     : YES

  DAR SUITE command line programs:
   Long options available : YES
   Building examples      : NO
   Building dar_static    : YES
   using upx at install   : NO
   building documentation : NO
```

Finish:

```
make
sudo make DESTDIR=/usr/bin install-strip
dar -V
dar: error while loading shared libraries: libdar.so.5000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I need help...

**UPD:** info about ubuntu package [dar_2.4.2-1_i386.deb](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/dar_2.4.2-1_i386.deb.html) and my [install log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46074116/install.log)